# Les Françaises ou Les Français?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, accord

J'ai souvent entendu « Les Françaises » pour parler de toutes les personne françaises . Mais, pourquoi est-elle féminin (françaises) et pas masculin (français) ?

Peut-être, c'est parce que « personne » est féminin ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Les Françaises: ce mot se réfère aux femmes (de la France) uniquement.
- Les Français: Selon le contexte, ce mot peut se référer aussi bien aux  hommes (de la France) uniquement qu'aux  femmes et  hommes ensemble.

Comment: Merci. Je pensais que c'est ça, mais je voulais le confirmer